# How do you continue to ask for integers and add them in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in range(assignment_quantity):
    assignment_grade = int(input("What was your grade on assignment#" + str(i) + ":"))
    print(assignment_grade)
    total_assignment_grade = assignment_grade
    complete = total_assignment_grade + assignment_grade
    print(complete)
```

The user is supposed to continue entering numbers and the code is supposed to add the numbers before adding more numbers the user input; I am extremely stuck on this.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Do you have an upper limit to how many times you want to fetch user input? If that is same as `assignment_quantity` it should work. Also `total_assignment_grade` is used wrongly I think

Comment: The limit is set by assignment_quantity

Comment: Then maybe you want to set `total_assignment_grade` to 0 outside loop and inside loop use `total_assignment_grade += assignment_grade` and finally print `total_assignment_grade` when loop is over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding `total_assignment_grade` each round so `complete` is just 2x what ever you gave as input. You need to add to `complete` what ever was given as input:

```
assignment_quantity = 3

complete = 0

for i in range(assignment_quantity):
    assignment_grade = int(input("What was your grade on assignment#" + str(i) + ":"))
    print(assignment_grade)
    complete += assignment_grade
    print(complete)
```